# How to transform an object during conversion to json?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api

I have a flat DTO object with ~500 fields that is returned via an API call.  The .NET machinery converts it to JSON and all is good.  It looks like this:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "desc": "foo",
  "system": "axmls",
  "bedrooms": 5,
  "flooring": "tile",
  "roof": "tesla",
  ...
  ...
}
```

Now I am being asked to place these ~500 fields into categories to make it look similar to this:

```
{
  "main": {
    "id": 1,
    "desc": "foo",
    "system": "axmls",
    ...
  }
  "interior": {
    "bedrooms": 5,
    "flooring": "tile",
    ...
  }
  "exterior": {
    "roof": "tesla",
    ...
  }
}
```

I've thought of couple of ways to doing this (none too enticing)

1. Create a new object to match this structure and copy data to it.  Not great.
2. Build JSON by hand.  No.
3. Mark each field on the original object with a Category attribute and then somehow in a FilterAttribute transform it.  This one sounds most promising, though I am not sure how to implement it.

Is there a way to create a JSON structure like this in a sane manner?

Comment: Consider [JSONata](https://jsonata.org/).

Comment: Build a metadata dictionary (string, string) that maps each item (bedrooms, flooring, roof) to categories (main, interior, exterior). Read the data you have (the big initial list) into a `Dictionary<string, string>`. Then walk that Dictionary, looking up the category in the metadata. Finally populate a `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>` with the results and serialize it back out to JSON

Comment: _Create a new object to match this structure and copy data to it. Not great._ - Is simplest way to do it. Maintainable, readable, because reader can see that we expose different data structure. Maintainable because you will have only one method which converts original data structure into one we send out.

Comment: If you want a very simple implementation of what @Fabio proposes, take a look at my answer below.  Simple, maintainable, self documenting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I described in the comments.  First, you need some metadata.  I use an enum here (since it makes typos less likely - though it does make the code ever so slightly more complicated.

(**UPDATE**: I found a bug, I was treating everything as strings. now I treat the leaf nodes of the trees as `object`)

First the category types:

```
private enum CategoryName
{
    Main,
    Interior,
    Exterior,
}
```

and the category metadata:

```
private static readonly Dictionary<string, CategoryName> _categoryMetadata =
    new Dictionary<string, CategoryName>
    {
        {"id", CategoryName.Main},
        {"desc", CategoryName.Main},
        {"system", CategoryName.Main},
        {"bedrooms", CategoryName.Interior},
        {"flooring", CategoryName.Interior},
        {"roof", CategoryName.Exterior}
    };
```

Now, your input JSON.  Note that I single-quoted the strings, it makes it easier to use in C# and doesn't change the nature of the JSON.  I also took out all your `...` entries:

```
 private const string InputJson = @"
 {
     'id': 1,
     'desc': 'foo',
     'system': 'axmls',
     'bedrooms': 5,
     'flooring': 'tile',
     'roof': 'tesla',
 }";
```

Finally the code.  As I described in the comments *"Build a metadata dictionary (string, string) that maps each item (bedrooms, flooring, roof) to categories (main, interior, exterior). Read the data you have (the big initial list) into a Dictionary<string, string>. Then walk that Dictionary, looking up the category in the metadata. Finally populate a Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> with the results and serialize it back out to JSON"*:

```
var output = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, object>>();
var input = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(InputJson);
foreach (var item in input)
{
    if (_categoryMetadata.TryGetValue(item.Key, out var category))
    {
        var categoryString = category.ToString().ToLower();
        if (!output.ContainsKey(categoryString))
        {
            output[categoryString] = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        }

        output[categoryString].Add(item.Key, item.Value);
    }
}

var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(output, Formatting.Indented);
```

When that's finished (and after my update), the JSON looks like:

```
{
  "main": {
    "id": 1,
    "desc": "foo",
    "system": "axmls"
  },
  "interior": {
    "bedrooms": 5,
    "flooring": "tile"
  },
  "exterior": {
    "roof": "tesla"
  }
}
```

In real life, you'd remove the `Formatting.Indented` parameter on the `JsonConvert.Serialize` call.

Comment: @AngryHacker: You probably want an `else` block after the `if (_categoryMetadata.TryGetValue(item.Key, out var category))` to signal that you have a missing category.  I generally don't put error checks in my sample code

Answer (score 0):

Just to visualise how simple it can look :)

```
public class House
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string System { get; set; }
    public int Bedrooms { get; set; }
    public string Flooring { get; set; }
    public string Roof { get; set; }
}
```

Publicly exposed structure without copying values

```
public class ExposedHouse
{        
    public Main Main { get; }
    public Interior Interior { get; }
    public Exterior Exterior { get; }

    public ExposedHouse(House house)
    {
        Main = new Main(house);
        Interior = new Interior(house);
        Exterior = new Exterior (house);
    }

    public class Main
    {
        private readonly House _house;

        public int Id => _house.Id;
        public string Description => _house.Description;
        public string System => _house.System;
   
        public Main(House house) { _house = house; }
    }

    public class Interior
    {
        private readonly House _house;

        public int Bedrooms => _house.Bedrooms;
        public string Flooring => _house.Flooring;

        public Interior(House house) { _house = house; }
    }

    public class Exterior
    {
        private readonly House _house;

        public string Roof => _house.Flooring;

        public Exterior(House house) { _house = house; }
    }
}
```

And conversion without copying values

```
var exposed = new ExposedHouse(house);
return Ok(exposed);
```

If requirements change in the future and you need to format some values differently, with this approach anybody will be able to do it :)

Comment: I am trying to avoid duplicating the object.  And keep in mind that it has 500+ properties.

Comment: I mean copying and pasting 500 items into the correct slots.  I just placed a Category attribute on the relevant properties and read them later via Reflection.

Comment: @AngryHacker, current approach doesn't copy values but "represents" them with different structure. This approach doesn't involve reflection "expensiveness" and provide nice base for other changes. For example if new requirements will need to format some specific values - for reflection approach you need to build/find/use another generic approach, but with this one - just jump into the code and change it ;)